# differences between C++ and C#

Tags: c#, c++

I know C++ but I am new to C# programming, and I have some questions:

1. I know that in C#, there is no "const correctness", so how do you replace it? if you call a method `f(Stack stk)`, how do you make sure that `f()` won't change my stack?
2. In c++ `operator=`,`copy ctor` and `dtor` are created automatically in every class, C# does it too?
3. I know that in C#, if we have a method `f(Stack stk)` , it's like `f(Stack& stk)` in c++,
   so how do I send object parameters by value?
4. in C#, we also create two files: `.h` for declarations and `.c` for implementation?

(Thanks!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. There is no const-ness of arbitrary types at all. Only individual *fields* can be `readonly`, not arbitrary variables or types. "Constants" (`const`) need to be compile-time constants, like pi.
2. Not for `class` types, because they can't be assigned to directly. `class` types are *always* handled via pointers, not direct manipulation of the objects. Only `struct`s can be manipulated directly, and those are always assigned via memory copy, so they have no assignment operators or destructor.
3. Variables that hold class "object" types are always *pointers* to the object, so to copy objects of class type, they need to implement `ICloneable`, and you're supposed to call `.Clone()` on the object and pass that. To copy struct objects, you can just pass them  normally.
4. No, the metadata is stored in the assembly itself.

Comment: 3 is wrong - that sends *value* parameters by *ref*, the OP wanted ref parameters by value, the other way round from what you had.

Comment: Thanks for comment, but in question 3, I wanted to pass arguments by value.(And my post is on board because I asked too many questions at once? so I should have opened 4 different posts?)

Comment: @slugster: Whoops, I misread, thanks!

Comment: @user3748682: Well, you should have opened 4 different posts, but in that case they would have all almost certainly been duplicates.

Comment: No probs :) I entered an answer too but was too slow, didn't get it finished before the question was closed.